# Guitar Pedal Simulator with LtSpice

Tags: analog, ltspice

I'm trying to simulate a guitar pedal with LtSpice. Do you know how I can input a guitar recording to the circuit? I will then convert the output to a txt to listen to it from Matlab sound function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wave files can be imported directly.

1. Copy the .wav file to the directory of the project
2. For the voltage source that you want to output the wav file, ctrl+click and edit the value field
   The value should say `wavefile=file.wav` (where file is the file name)

Source:
https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/5579265677001.html